# My react native app with expo takes a long time to load

Tags: react-native, performance, optimization, expo, load

I developed an application in react native using expo and I have a problem, the app takes a long time on the splash screen before starting, I didn't use any method to make the splash visible for a longer time. The issue occurs in both the development version and the production version.

Another point is that I read in an article that IIFE functions should be avoided inside useEffect, and so I removed the ones I used but I still have the performance problem, does anyone have any ideas on how to improve?

Answer (score 1):

If the connection is made but bundle building is very slow - Try disconnecting from the network both devices, and  reconnect your system . Also, don't forget to clear the 'recently in development' projects, terminals and start the project again. It will  increase the speed of building , especially for windows it works very well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem is that after generating the production version, the app takes a long time to get past the splash screen.